# How to add a CAPTCHA to sign up experience in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, captcha, azure-active-directory

I'm looking into the new Azure AD B2C service. It allows customization of the sign-up experience, but I don't see any option to incorporate a CAPTCHA.

This [TechNet blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2015/09/16/azure-ad-b2c-and-b2b-are-now-in-public-preview.aspx) says the service performs some kind of "anomaly detection" during sign up, but doesn't specifically claim to be actively detecting and blocking robots.

Is anti-robot testing somehow provided automatically, without any additional steps for the user, or if not, how can I customize the experience to incorporate a CAPTCHA?

Answer (score 2):

Today the UX customization in B2C is purely for allowing you to match the look and feel of your apps, but AFAIK there is no ay of introducing active elements (e.g. anything that would run code). The service does provide email verification checks, but I can see how you might want to have something more specific. I will flag this thread with our B2C expert to see if there's anything more that can be shared at this time.

Comment: Thanks. Looking forward to more info on this.

Comment: @vibronet, Hey any update on this related to CAPTCHA?